# Is present-day nazism correlated with their countries' allegiance in WWII?

Tags: nazism

Although I've rarely heard it said explicitly, I've got a suspicion that some people assume that people in places that were Axis Powers (including Germany and Japan) during WWII are more likely to be nazis than people from Allied Powers or neutral countries.

Is there a correlation between whether a country was an Axis Power, and nazism in that country? And if so, is it a positive correlation (people in those countries are more likely to be nazis), or a negative correlation?

In addition, do other factors, such as the country's geopolitical alliances subsequent to WWII (such as the Cold War), or the ethnic background of a person, influence the frequency of nazism?

By "nazism", I mean groups that purposely brand themselves as similar to the original nazism. Just being racist and authoritarian doesn't count. So the Nationalsozialistische Japanische Arbeiterpartei (NSJAP) would count as nazi, but the [Zaitokukai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaitokukai) (Citizens against the Special Privileges of the Zainichi) wouldn't.

Comment: This seems to be pretty self-referential and "No true scotsman" to boot. Of course a neo-nazi group in Russia won't brand itself as "Nazi", but it walks and quacks like a real Nazi duck.

Comment: Also, there's a major political imging issue here, since for example there's a tendency in far-left liberal countries to label any nationalist party "nazi" (hell, USA Democrats liberally - pun intended - apply it to GOP, which shows just how meaningless the term became in modern political vernacular).

Comment: @DVK I thought it'd be necessary to try to define nazism! George Orwell complained about the term "fascist" being liberally used, and that was barely after WWII. Regarding the first comment, if you do a web or image search for "Neo Nazis In Russia (9 Photos)", you get a Nazi Germany flag being used.

Comment: There's self-labeled neo-Nazis in Russia. There's a LOT more ones who are 100% neo-Nazi by any reasonable definition but don't self identify as such and actively reject the comparison for political optics view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is there a correlation between whether a country was an Axis Power, and nazism in that country?*

**Short answer:** Half of today's world neo-nazis (by membership) are citizens of the Russia. The direct answer depends on whether to consider Russia a German ally (before 1941) or an enemy.

---

[image: Russian neo-nazis]
<sup>Russian neo-nazis. Image [from here](http://www.trust.ua/news/95089-fashisty-rossii--tajnyj-rezerv-kremlya.html)</sup>

By 2011, in Russia there were about 150 radical organizations [(proof, in Russian)](http://www.trust.ua/news/95089-fashisty-rossii--tajnyj-rezerv-kremlya.html).

*Offtopic: [on this image on the same page](http://www.trust.ua/files/photo/source/0000036779-gubarev-rne.jpg), one may see [Pavel Gubarev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Gubarev), known in 2014 as the "People's Governor" of the "Donetsk People's Republic".*

Out of 150 radical organizations, about 53 can be considered neo-nazi ones [(proof, in Russian)](http://www.cogita.ru/a.n.-alekseev/andrei-alekseev-1/nacionalisticheskie-organizacii-v-rossii-2013-umerennye-radikalnye-i-zapreschennye).

[Here's a list](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/ru%7Dnaz.html) of the most active neo-nazi groups in the Russia;

> [In the Russia], there are now an estimated **50,000 to 70,000 neo-Nazis, half of the world's total**. They even have supporters in parliament. [(ABC News)](http://abcnews.go.com/Nightline/story?id=3718255&page=1)

[This article](http://wiadomosci.dziennik.pl/swiat/artykuly/104227,neonazisci-w-rosji-grozniejsi-od-czeczenow.html) (in Polish) quotes Alexander Wierchowskij, head of the Moscow's analytical center "SOWA":

> Currently, it is estimated that the neo-Nazi movement in Russia has up to **70 thousand members**.

**So, it is evident that the majority of world's neo-nazis are citizens of the Russia.**

Now, to answer directly on your question, we have to consider that Russia has been [a loyal ally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact) of Germany in 1932-1941, but then turned into the Axis enemy.

Comment: How the politics before WWII related to modern Russian politics? I think no organization in Russia, however radical (including Neo-Nazis), thinks the USSR was an ally to Germany in 1939. At most such accusations could be heared only from Eastern European anti-Russian nationalists.

Comment: @Anixx Please take your time to read the question. It was about the correlation between *Axis allies during WWII* and *modern-day Nazis*. The Russia of 1939 has been a loyal ally of the Nazi Germany. If one wants to discuss this fact, let's start with some explanation of the [German–Soviet military parade in Brest-Litovsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German%E2%80%93Soviet_military_parade_in_Brest-Litovsk) on **22 September 1939**, for example.

Comment: Very funny that you brought it here. Brest-Litovsk parade was a part of ceremony of transferring control of the city from Germans to the Soviets. German flag was removed and Soviet one raised in the presence of the Soviet officers who were observing the Germans' departure. The allies had a lot of similar "parades" with Germans and the Japanese in 1945 when cities surrendered.

Comment: "transferring control" of a sovereign country's territory to a Germany's non-ally, you mean? :)

Comment: In 1945 they even transferred cities to their adversaries... In quite a similar way. Or even more pompous. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:German%E2%80%93Soviet_military_parade_in_Brest-Litovsk#mediaviewer/File:More042.jpg , http://www.wehrmacht-awards.com/campaign_awards/cufftitles/metz/9.jpg

Comment: In 1945 they have **surrendered**. It's a bit different to a voluntary action like a military parade for two armies, isn't it?

Comment: Count this parade also as peaceful "surrender" if u wish. The "parade" was only by Germans. Soviet officers were observing how the Germans were leaving. Or one can call it a march or troops departure, because the units were moving to leave the city. This or that way they had to move in columns.

Comment: [**Soviet troops decorated with swastikas** and red stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German%E2%80%93Soviet_military_parade_in_Brest-Litovsk), yes. Not an ally, no-no-no.

Comment: The archs were erected in another town (its name is known, I can search for u) at different date and time. There were no such things in Brest-Litovsk, it is a debunked lie.

Answer (score 6):

Neo-Nazi movements most definitely [do NOT confine themselves to the Axis, or specific sides in Cold War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Nazism).

- There's ton's of neo-Nazis in [Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Nazism#Russia).

  In reality there's a lot more than are listed since many pretend to NOT be neo-Nazi (but fit to a T ideology wise).
- There are neo-Nazis in [USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Nazism#United_States) and UK. Which isn't that surprising as there were fascist parties and sympathizers in both countries even before WWII (Charles Lindbergh and Henry Ford and Lord Haw-Haw being more well known examples).
- Heck, while not widespread, immigrants from fUSSR form neo-Nazi cells **[in Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Nazism#Israel)**

Comment: "In reality there's a lot more than are listed since many pretend to NOT be neo-Nazi (but fit to a T ideology wise)." - is Vladimir Putin one of them?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Not ideologically. Putin is a typical pragmatic leader - he'll use nazis as one of his levers of power when/where warranted, but he doesn't really have a strong ideology himself to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score -6):

Even if a party to some extent empathizes connection to Germany's National Socialism, they may empathize different sides of the ideology. A neo-Nazi from the US most likely would be white supremacist and anti-Muslim, a Neo-Nazi from Russia would be most likely an antisemite, while a Neo-Nazi from Latvia or Estonia or Ukraine would be most likely anti-Russian. Thus, I would group Neo-Nazi movements geographically. This does not refer to particular organizations, but the general trends.

- Type I. The Western Europe and the USA. In these countries the Neo-Nazis are most likely be white supremacists, anti-immigrant, anti-Muslim. They empathize eugenics and Nordicism in the Hitlerist ideology. They may be friendly to negative towards Russia and Israel. They tend to deny or downplay the Holocaust. They often openly admire Hitler.
- Type II. The Eastern Europe and former Soviet republics, excluding Russia. In this zone the Neo-Nazis are mostly anti-Russian, anti-Communist and pro-Western. They support the role of Nazi Germany in anti-russian struggle and anti-Communism. They may be friendly to neutral towards Israel and generally friendly to Muslims in the post-Soviet area, but neutral to negative to those outside. They often deny support for Hitler but heroize the fighters of pro-Nazi SS units of Eastern Europe, Caucasus and Central Asia, claiming they are not complicit in the Nazi atrocities or blaiming the atrocities to Germany's proper forces, or claiming the Soviets did worse.
- Type III. The Russia itself. These are mostly anti-Western, anti-American and antisemitic. They empathize the role of Nazi Germany in exterminating the Jews, and even if not endorsing Hitler's regime as it was because of his anti-russian attitude, call for conducting similar policy towards Jewish parasites in Russia. They usually do not deny Holocaust, but conversely, usually support it as "the thing Hitler did right, dispite other mistakes". One of the Hitler's mistakes in their view was the invasion in Russia instead of allying with her against the West and the Jews. They may be negative to friendly towards Europe (conditionally on how the Europe bahaves towards the USA) and Muslims (they usually oppose Muslims in Russia but support them abroad) but always negative to Israel and the USA. They are usually neutral towards the Soviets and Stalinism.

Recently the US made efforts to introduce the "type II" Nazis (so-called "National-democrats") into Russian politics, but unsuccessfully so far, those groups were exposed as "fake Nazis", and the Washington's hand was alleged.

In countries which were not touched by the WWII there is usually much less popularity of the Nazis than in those countries which were. Although Neo-Nazis may exist there as well, such as in Mongolia where the Neo-Nazis are usually anti-Chinese.

Comment: Any citations from reliable sources for the second last paragraph?

Comment: Or any of your diatribe for that matter.

Comment: would've upvoted except for the second last paragraph made it a downvote.