Why does the Ukrainian government fund and tolerate Far-Right extremist, despite being liberal?
I noticed an ideological contradiction, the way the Ukrainian government tries to present itself and the way they act.
Under the Zelenskyy administration, there were a couple of policies and proposals that can be considered liberal and progressive. At the same time, under his government and party people and organizations have been receiving funding, state recognition and PR promotion. Additionally, the utter inability to make visual impact assessment, be it to check for Neo-Nazi symbols before western journalist come over, to an entire military unit using a Neo-Nazi symbols, makes one wonder about the seriousness of the Ukrainian government claims of not having a Neo-Nazi problem.
In any other western, especially liberal government, nothing even close would be tolerated in the military. In fact, most of them try to align the military to their ideology.
Why does the Ukrainian government fund and tolerate Far-Right extremist, despite being liberal?

Historically, a significant component of Ukrainian nationalism and rejection of Russia can be traced to Bandera, who was a fairly nasty specimen.  People can hold many different beliefs and mix some good ones (wanting to be a free country) with really bad ones.  Are you saying that one Azov brigade's ideological underpinnings - which may also not align as much with Bandera as you imply outside of Russophobia - negate the country's overall right to independence?  Or that in the midst of an existential war, the country need to "purify" its military ideologically?

Bear in mind that neo-Nazis in the military are an issue that goes beyond Ukraine. The USA historically has had issues, as have Russia, Germany and others.

The degree to which the Azov Brigade historically was organized and open about its ideology is somewhat anomalous—only somewhat —but the relative numbers (compared to the size of the military) are not particularly unusual. Fascists of all stripes tend to be attracted to militaries both as a realization of their hierarchical ideals, and as a source of recruits and weapons for their plans.

Why does Germany fund Neo Nazi Special Forces? The level of toleration is not what you think. The seemingly random collection of links in this Q makes it hard to understand what is really asked here. The German Luftwaffe still has nearly the same symbol (modulo minor curvature changes) and exactly the same name, BTW. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Air_Force#/media/File:Bundeswehr_Logo_Luftwaffe_with_lettering.svg As the Ukrainian unit you say it's "Neo Nazi".

Anyway, the topic has been more or less covered before https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71492/who-are-the-alleged-nazis-in-the-ukraine-government

@264champagnebottlesonice it doesn't that's the point. "The German Luftwaffe"  yeah but it's symbol is not formed like an SS division and most importantly is not derived from a previous army but inspired by it. There is no plausible deniability in this. Somebody created and approved the design. They understand what it means and the leadership for some reason approved it despite it giving ammo.  "you say it's "Neo Nazi"." If you use a design specifically unique to the WAFFEN SS, you may deserve such accusation. At least it's not a subtle symbol like the OK sign or milk.

"like an SS division". You assume those logos particularly for new drone units, created in the middle of a war, receive a lot of official scrutiny. It's not clear to me that unit subordinated to the 129th Territorial Defense Brigade has an official logo that was approved at any higher level. The drone unit doesn't even appear in the official composition of the brigade on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/129th_Territorial_Defense_Brigade_(Ukraine) although it may be because that wasn't updated in a while.

I see it does show up on the Ukrainian-language page https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/129-%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8_(%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0) Perhaps a better Q here would be who approves those sub-unit logos.

@264champagnebottlesonice No, I'm not assuming it. But the few who see it and don't have a strange cognitive dissonance are a bit shocked and disgusted. Certainly not much helps in the Nazi narrative. Additionally there are https://www.facebook.com/share/p/1EsHqrdHgA/        https://www.facebook.com/share/p/1FUcYSNiDn/   yeah a bandera flag and an eagle shaped similarly like the Luftwaffen SS Eagle. Very subtle. It's not some no name irregulars like the Freikorps but a part of the Ukrainian army. Somebody approved it. And your odd try to defend this falls on a deaf ear.

BTW, the shoulder patch that the cmdr or that sub-unit wears is still the brigade's logo  https://rudana.com.ua/sites/default/files/styles/full_size_gal/public/inline/images/406648075_3660090147588802_2241798172866749421_n.jpg?itok=ufOp0RdZ It's not clear to me if the sub-unit logo is more than a facebook thing.

BTW, some other units created during this war use Warhammer 40K Chaos names and insignias. While some might find that amusing, one could equally question the sanity of praising the gods of destruction as semi-official unit ideology.

Actually, the cmdr of that sub-unit does wear the new shoulder patch in some of the (presumably more recent) photos https://rudana.com.ua/sites/default/files/styles/full_size_gal/public/inline/images/463181633_3905786269685854_5584527853808754572_n.jpg?itok=Yc8iav1Q You could make a Q here who approves those.

BTW, it looks like all these unmanned systems batallions were created this year, or this summer
https://www.csis.org/analysis/why-ukraine-establishing-unmanned-forces

A bit more search shows these battalions were serially created, there's 420, 421 and 423 which are of the same kind. Most try to have some kind of flying something as part of the unit patch https://420obbps.com/ Probably someone had to mass approve these logos this year or this summer. Even those units that don't have a chipped shield have a black one, which someone could say still looks a bit SS. https://militaryland.net/ukraine/unmanned-systems-forces/423rd-battalion-of-unmanned-systems/ (Not all SS divisions had a chipped shield.) Perhaps you could make a Q about all of them.

BTW, Russia also likes to complain that Ukrainians and Westerners in general are satanists etc. At least one Ukrainian unit seem to like to oblige with that "Devil's Team" with a logo to match
https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/1h3ojch/ukrainian_soldiers_of_the_sof_unit_devils_team/

@264champagnebottlesonice - Strictly speaking, it's the Emperor of Mankind who is space Hitler. The Ruinous Powers are like...space Satan or something.

@Obie2.0 they are an issue but they don't fund encourage it and or lie about it. In fact western militaries actively try to purge their military and law enforcement of Nazis influence whenever they have the possibility.  Its at least in my mind logical as Nazis oppose almost everything modern liberals believe.

I managed to find an interview with the cmdr of that 422 unit. Alas only in Ukrainian. But it does touch on the naming https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/aerorozvidka-interviu-luftwaffe/33007291.html

@ItalianPhilosopher I did not say in any way that Ukraine does not have a right to exist neither did I mention Azov. My question is, even before the war, the mostly liberal government of Ukraine funded  neo-nazis and neo-Nazi projects and gave them government positions, which confuses me. As Neonazis are the greatest antithesis to a liberal order then even Anarchist or Communist because they agree at least on Equality and giving minorities preferential treatment. Azov isn't the greatest confusement (even though it is confusing why Ukrainians threat it like the only Battalion in the army).

@ItalianPhilosopher My confusion is that the liberal government is funding its own rope which they might get hanged with it. And additionally proving Russian propaganda right. Because it isn't Russia that is dependent on Western public opinion for funding, it is the Ukrainian government. And most Western people are not too keen on Nazis. Believe it or not. The fact that they are utterly incapable, at least order their soldiers to remove their death head and black sun from their uniforms when journalists come over is confusing too.

@264champagnebottlesonice yeah it's funny to embrace certain names as tongue in cheek way to troll somebody. But in cases like this it's not appropriate knowing how much your country is reliant on foreign citizens to be sympathetic to you. And images like that, knowing our relationship with Nazism, knowing how suddenly the media pretends Nazism is not a big deal in Ukraine cause Russia says it does not make it better. How do you guys not get it?

This question is fine and should be opened. There’s a good basis for an answer on political expediency

People are not exactly lining up to die for liberal cause. The whole trope of liberal worldview is about attaining individual goals in this world, which is not conductive with dying for a cause.
Liberal states may have a paid professional army but its morale in case of all-out war is questionable.
That is where nationalism or religious zealotry comes into the picture. Liberal states have money but one can observe they rely either on nationalists or jihadists for motivated troops. They could use communists as well but that does not seem to happen these days.

"They could use communists as well but that does not seem to happen these days." - too much risk of blowback I suppose. What they ideally need is a series of warring groups, each willing to act as the instrument of destruction for the prior, then the last of which dies off in the cold every winter.

Liberals are actually quite adept at removing extremists from political positions. In Ukraine, far-right parties always had single digits of votes. Don't even need to kill them off.

You mean removing their own extreme opponents, and keeping up appearances? I accept they don't want Ukrainian Nazis running the gaff, especially if they are characteristically anti-liberal and too ideological to be corrupted. That's why they install someone like Zelensky at the top. But they were nevertheless happy to use the Ukrainian Nazis as cannon fodder, having nurtured them at the grassroots for a while.

"They could use communists as well"
They do for some reason.
https://www.city-journal.org/article/a-slush-fund-for-radical-protesters
https://nypost.com/2023/03/26/who-funds-antifa-protests-we-all-do/

@Questioner I'm not sure Antifa are relevant since their values are essentially liberal. They don't plan on dying for a cause. One can make komissars out of them but poor soldiers.

@alamar Antifa for most of those groups are anything but liberal. It's like calling Groypers or Indentitärens conservative. They are right-wing but on a different level.

Two reasons.
First, they are trying to marshal the entire forces of the liberal-controlled West, and therefore benefit from to presenting themselves within the usual liberal norms.
Second, they need people to actually fight in this case, and an alliance with local right-wing nationalists was convenient in getting Zelensky elected in the first place, then getting the war going against Russia (once open war became the case) and amply supplying the initial manpower for the fronts.
It's a mistake to think the liberal is intolerant of Nazis. Obviously they prefer overt managerial control by ideological liberals. But when they cannot have that, the only crucial question is whether the Nazis represent the rich interests of liberals or not. If they don't, they'll be deemed "far-right" and "a threat to world peace" and all that. If they do, the liberal seeks to co-opt the leadership and provide alternative support from the grassroots - as you're seeing in the US as liberals cozy up to Trump and try to steer him away from popular policies that will harm liberal interests.

"It's a mistake to think the liberal is intolerant of Nazis. "
I however see this on a daily basis in the west. Be it from activly funding antifascist activist, to extensive online censorship, to government designations. Nazis at least in the liberal west are treated like a existential treat which could wipe out their institutions if left unbeaten. It's also ironic that any presence of Nazis no matter how small can lead to an entire movement being social ousted. Like the Trucker protestors, various populist parties in EU or smaller political personalities.

"US as liberals cozy up to Trump"
Thats kinda new to me.
I know Zuckerberg has given a more positiv term on him, but aren't they as mad as previously?

@Questioner, as I say, I'm not saying the liberal prefers fascism to liberalism. I'm saying when they can't have liberalism, they back fascism. Many of them have certainly treated Trump like an existential threat whilst trying to win the election - but now they are beaten, they seek accomodation with the supposed existential threat instead, the co-option to which I refer. Liberals are a political force, not a centralised organisation or a mechanical horse, and different liberals are capable of making different judgments and engaging in different behaviours at different times.

Zelensky was Russia's preferred alternative in that election, just so you know.

@ItalianPhilosopher, interesting point, is there any more info available about that?

I have posted answers referencing just that, yes.  They're not hard to find.  Initially there was a lot of Western concerns about Zelensky's election, that he was going to be a weak leader, too prone to concessions to Putin.  You can easily do your own research.

@ItalianPhilosopher, I'm sure it's bona fide, I just can't find any information on it, and I've never heard the point before. What I can find so far suggests Zelensky's competitors in the election characterised him as pro-Russia, whilst he adopted a conciliatory tone on various Russia-related issues. But I can't find anything saying Russia actually tipped him as their "preferred alternative" (which presumably would have unhelpfully confirmed his competitors' accusations?).

2019... : On Monday, Russian officials expressed satisfaction at Poroshenko’s defeat and some optimism about Zelensky.

@ItalianPhilosopher, it sounds like the Russians were glad to be shut of Poroshenko more than anything, and welcomed Zelensky's compromising rhetoric. The spokesmen were also remarking after the election, where there may often be a tendency to gild the lily a little.
